# python2.7 - json encoder - Why object isn't serializable

Tags: json, python-2.7, openedx

I am finding following error in code, Can someone please guide me why I am finding this error and how can I fix it.

**I LOGGED response before its used in Response(json.dumps(response), content_type='application/json', charset='utf8'):-**

```
[service_variant=lms][root][env:sandbox] WARNING [waleed-HP-Compaq-Elite-8300-CMT  32269] [mixins.py:75] - (json.dumps(response)-- {'url': u'/openassessment/fileupload/submissions_attachments/a419e1fff5e9a869a46d537c7ae3a18a/course-v1:edX+DemoX+Demo_Course/block-v1:edX+DemoX+Demo_Course+type@openassessment+block@051fae2bdc4f47929078eda8463a8c44/', 'success': True}
```

> [service_variant=lms][courseware.module_render][env:sandbox] ERROR
>   [waleed-HP-Compaq-Elite-8300-CMT  32269] [module_render.py:1210] -
>   error executing xblock handler

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/edx-platform/lms/djangoapps/courseware/module_render.py", line 1185, in _invoke_xblock_handler
    resp = handler_instance.handle(handler, req, suffix)
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xblock/mixins.py", line 91, in handle
    return self.runtime.handle(self, handler_name, request, suffix)
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/edx-platform/common/lib/xmodule/xmodule/x_module.py", line 1365, in handle
    return super(MetricsMixin, self).handle(block, handler_name, request, suffix=suffix)
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xblock/runtime.py", line 1037, in handle
    results = handler(request, suffix)
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xblock/mixins.py", line 76, in wrapper
    return Response(json.dumps(response), content_type='application/json', charset='utf8')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 244, in dumps
    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 207, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 270, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 184, in default
    raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
```

**ERROR:-**

```
TypeError: u'/openassessment/fileupload/submissions_attachments/a419e1fff5e9a869a46d537c7ae3a18a/course-v1:edX+DemoX+Demo_Course/block-v1:edX+DemoX+Demo_Course+type@openassessment+block@051fae2bdc4f47929078eda8463a8c44/' is not JSON serializable
```

Comment: How did you set up/enable the file uploads in ORA? Is everything okay with that?

Comment: @IsankaWijerathne regarding ORA setup I mentioned details here : https://discuss.openedx.org/t/open-response-assignment-ora-upload-file-could-not-retrieve-upload-url/829

Comment: Actually I am trying to upload files into local filesystem.

Comment: Then it may be "ora2-storage" cache settings in lms.env.json. check that.

Comment: @IsankaWijerathne for ironwood release "default" cache settings in lms.env.json is available. And I am already using it.

Comment: I can see in past regisb also found same error - https://github.com/overhangio/tutor/issues/97#issuecomment-441301113